# Retrieve sum value from two different tables MySQL and ordering

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my DB, dbl1_profiletype and dbl1_users.

In dbl1_profiletype I have the columns with the "id" and "name"

```
id__name
3___red
5___blue
6___white
7___green
8___brown
```

And in the dbl1_users I have the columns with the "userid" and "profile", where the "profile" value is the same as the "id" value from the dbl1_profiletype table.

[image: dbl1_users]

What I want to show is one table like that in the image below:

[image: TOTAL_MEMBERS]

So, what I need is to return a list with the sum number of members by profiletype, ordered by the profiletype with more members and with the profiletype with smaller number of members lastly.
I tried to SELECT name and COUNT(profile) like that:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(profile)

FROM  dbl1_profiletype, dbl1_users 

GROUP BY profile
```

But it doesnt work.

And I have also tried:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(profile)

FROM  dbl1_profiletypes, dbl1_users 

GROUP BY profile
```

Without sucess to.

I am noob in mysql, but I suspect that it may be something simple to achieve but that is beyond my comprehension at the moment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are the two attempts different?

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, you are joining the tables without join conditions

Comment: Sorry my mistake. 
The other attempt I made was to use the join syntax. But like I said, I am noob in mysql.

Comment: Any tutorial on SQL joins should explain what you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i came up with the information provided by you. I think you are missing the `JOIN` conditions,

```
SELECT DBL1_PROFILETYPE.NAME MEMBERS
    , COUNT(*) TOTAL
FROM DBL1_USERS
    JOIN DBL1_PROFILETYPE 
        ON DBL1_USERS.PROFILETYPE = DBL1_PROFILETYPE.ID
GROUP BY DBL1_PROFILETYPE.NAME
```

Comment: Thats it! The only thing is that the order is not correct. I need the highest value first and the lower value last. Like the image that I show in my post. Red 4, then Green 2, Blue 2, Brown 1, white 0.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do it. ORDER BY TOTAL DESC.